# Incorrect line in Line & clustered column chart in powerBI, 164mn is pointing downwards &167.7 &167.5 is pointing right, how to correct this?

Tags: powerbi, dax, linechart

Inconsistency in the line and clustered column chart, if you notice in the first bar chart 164 mn is pointing downwards whereas 167.7 and 167.5mn line is showing rightly? is there a way we can fix this so that the line shows consistently?

Inconsistency in the line across the bar chart

[image]

Comment: This is currently not possible. I think [this is an idea you can vote for](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/14130033-better-data-label-customization) that someone created.

Comment: Is there any better way I can show the totals for entire bar chart?

Comment: There is no easy way to do that in Power BI. [Take a look at this solution](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Display-total-on-top-of-stacked-chart/td-p/6697) for the Power BI community. It says to put a hidden bar chart behind the stacked and it will show the total values

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you have 2 Y-axis (left and right).
So the solution is to combine 2 axis into 1 by following the steps as shown in the images.
[image: screenshot Y axis]

[image: screenshot Off]